# Write a simple Bootloader HelloWorld - Error function print string

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, bootloader

I try to create a simple bootloader which print "hello world".

I can do it when I call a function which only print "hello world", but when I call a function to print a specific string, nothing is happening.

For it, I use two files. The first one is boot.ld and the second is boot.cpp (it also work in C with boot.c).

Firstly, I create the floppy disk from my terminal:

> dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy.img bs=512 count=2880

Secondly, I compile the code (boot.cpp and boot.ld):

> gcc -c -g -Os -m64 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror boot.cpp -o boot.o
>
> ld -static -Tboot.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o boot.elf boot.o
>
> objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin

Lastly, I add boot.bin into floppy.img:

> dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.img

Now we just need to add the floppy from the storage panel of VirtualBox and launch our Virtual Machine.

[image: FloppyImage]

**The source code**

*from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664165/Writing-a-boot-loader-in-Assembly-and-C-Part*

boot.ld

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        *(.text);
    }
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
}
```

boot.cpp (or boot.c)

```
void cout();

void main()
{
    cout();
}

void cout()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'h' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'e' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'l' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'l' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'o' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $' ' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'w' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'o' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'r' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'l' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $'d' , %al\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");
}
```

**Output:**

[image: TestBootLoader1]

**The bugged source code**

boot.cpp (or boot.c)

```
void cout(const char* str);

void main()
{
    cout("hello world");
}

void cout(const char* str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("int $0x10" : : "a"(0x0e00 | *str), "b"(0x0007));
        ++str;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: TestBootLoader2]

Why the output is empty?

What is wrong in my function?

I have forget something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try checking disassembly, may be it will shed a light to the problem.

Comment: Nop, I can compile it properly... It didn't print any error message :/

Comment: He meant you should look at the generated assembly anyways. Btw, I suspect `-m64` could maybe not work with `.code16` (which you don't show, btw, but it is necessary to emit real-mode compatible code). The article you link is a bit outdated, both `gcc` and `clang` now support the `-m16` flag which will use `.code16` automatically.

Comment: So the problem happens when I compile it?
Why it works on the first example but not on the second? Also I cannot use -m16 (gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m16’).
I have check boot.bin with gHex for see if the compilation was completely finished - and yes.
But I don't know any softwares for see the assembly code of this format. IDA free doesn't work :/ Have you another one?

Comment: For the assembly code, use `gcc -S`. If your `gcc` doesn't know `-m16`, it's just to old, in that case, use `-m32` and put `__asm__ __volatile__(".code16 \n");` first in your code.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Oh no! Don't do that! That'll mess up GCC's assumptions that it can generate 32-bit code!

Comment: Use `-O0` instead of `-Os`, I'm beginning to think something messes up the *optimization-for-size*. It should fit either way. If you have access to `clang`, try compiling your source with the same flags and see if the result is any different.

Comment: @KemyLand which is perfectly fine, because `-m16` does exactly the same. The `.code16` just instructs the assembler to emit 32bit instruction length prefixes in the binary, so it works in real mode. No version of `gcc` can emit REAL 16bit code.

Comment: I think the single biggest flaw you have in your code is that you don't set up the `ds` register at all. It is possible it isn't what it is expected to be. Given your linker (boot.ld) settings you should be putting 0 into `ds`. The other problem is that I suspect that your boot.ld linker may not even being placing your string in the final binary since I see no mention of the .data segment (or the .rodata segment). That code project article is a piece of poorly written crap (IMHO). A lot of errors. He's just lucky it worked at all.

Comment: Ok so I can compile with `-O0` but the output is still empty. I download clang right now. @FelixPalmen I can add `__asm__ __volatile__(".code16 \n");` but after, I cannot use the command `ld` anymore.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: And that's what I meant. If `gcc` can't emit actual (non-tricking) real mode code, then it's not situable for something such as critical as a bootloader. Anyway, `-m16` is not enough. There are features of protected mode that are unavailable from real mode, that `gcc` may rely on, for instance, SIMD. Or even the fact that protected mode (usually) uses a plain memory model (assumed by GCC, too), but real mode uses that creepy segmentation **always**.

Comment: @KemyLand it's not a good option, but it should work fine for some simple playing around. You can't use more than one segment, indeed ... I recently made a little console game work with this as a DOS .COM binary: https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos

Comment: @FelixPalmen: No doubts may I have on that :).

Comment: Clang doesn't work. So all the source code is wrong? If I understand KemyLand's answer, I have to rewrite all?
`boot.cpp:1:9: error: meaningless 'volatile' on asm outside function [-Werror]
__asm__ __volatile__(".code16 \n");
       ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.`

Comment: When it's not inside a function, the volatile is indeed meaningless. Just drop it so clang doesn't complain any more.

Comment: @FelixPalmen : If he were to use GCC with experimental 16bit code generation the proper place for `__asm__ __volatile__ (".code16\n");` is right at the top of the boot.c file outside the functions

Comment: @MichaelPetch as `gcc` is now supporting `-m16` to do all this automatically (as well as clang), this would be the "proper" way. Just get a recent version of either compiler... (this of course doesn't include `ds`, you have to handle it indeed)

Comment: Sure, however older versions without `-m16` may already support it as well. He hasn't said what version of his C compiler he is using. But you guys are also missing the fundamental flaw about `ds` which is obviously going to be a problem when accessing the string `hello world`. I can see right off how the first version works and the second doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes, overlooked that ... my own code was always running from DOS, where `ds` was already set up :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen : As part of a bootloader you can't make any assumptions about any of the registers (including all the segment registers). The only guarantee you have is that code execution will start at physical address 0x00007c00 and that `dl` will contain the boot drive upon entry. Everything  else needs to be set up manually including a stack.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, I tryed some stuff. My gcc --version: `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4`. So right now the code look like that: http://pastebin.com/6NV3UMjE but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add `__asm__ __volatile__(".code16 \n");` to the very top of boot.cpp please?

Comment: If you want to disassemble the final bin file you create, I recommend installing the `ndisasm` package and then you can run this to disassemble it in 16 bits with `ndisasm -b16 boot.bin`

Comment: Ok, it's added. When now I cannot comile the code anymore. I get the error: `wrong registry name %rbx, %rdi`.

Comment: Yes, change your GCC line so you use `-m16` instead of `-m64`

Comment: And if that compiles you will need to alter your `ld` line to something like `ld -melf_i386 -static -Tboot.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o boot.elf boot.o`

Comment: One other thing I noticed (it won't be related to issues you are having) but you create a floppy image but then basically truncate it to 512 bytes when you do `dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.img` . I recommend using `dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.img conv=notrunc` so that the original floppy image you create doesn't get truncated down to the size of your boot loader.

Comment: -m16 doesn't exist :/
I have try `gcc -c -g -O0 -m32 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror boot.cpp -o boot.o`, `ld -melf_i386 -static -Tboot.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o boot.elf boot.o`, `objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin` and `dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.img conv=notrunc`. I am able to compile it but the output is still empty.
Maybe it is easier to rewrite it in assembly.

Comment: That is strange... With this code I get the output "S": http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/637207841.png

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention above that you need that JMPL (it is a far jmp) so that you jump to the beginning of your `main` function. `ENTRY(MAIN)` and has very little meaning in your boot.ld when you end up making a flat freestanding binary with ld and objcopy.

Comment: Here is the problem. I am doing this at 3am and I missed the obvious. I kept talking about 16bit experimental code generation. At the top of your file get ride of the __asm line with .code16 and try replacing it with `asm(".code16gcc")` . As well in your main your function has no where to return to. So after the call to `cout` hlt the processor with `__asm__ __volatile__("cli\n")` followed by `__asm__ __volatile__("hlt\n")`

Comment: You can do it in assembly but with the modifications I suggested I actually got it running here with "C". That is assuming your GCC supports .code16gcc

Comment: It's working!! Thanks you =)

Comment: i'll write up a proper answer when I wake up in the morning since you got it working. Too tired right now. Glad you got it going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  @[MichaelPetch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch) for this answer.

**Source code:**

boot.ld

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        *(.text);
    }
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
}
```

boot.cpp

*Also here: http://pastebin.com/6NV3UMjE*

```
asm(".code16gcc");
__asm__("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");

void cout(const char* str);

void main()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("xor %ax, %ax\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %ax, %ds\n");
    cout("Hello World");
    __asm__ __volatile__("cli\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__("hlt\n");
}

void cout(const char* str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x10" : : "a"(0x0e00 | *str), "b"(0x0007));
        ++str;
    }
}
```

**Compile:**

> gcc -c -g -O0 -m32 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror boot.cpp -o boot.o
>
> ld -melf_i386 -static -Tboot.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o boot.elf boot.o
>
> objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
>
> dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.img conv=notrunc

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: This an ugly fragile hack, and *will* cause tremendous problems in the future. Please read the [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/) and understand what does that solution that was gaven to you implies before proceeding. This is all to prevent you from getting in the same almost-undebuggable issues people have already came with while doing this sort of things.

Comment: Ok, let me take a coffee before and I start to read. Have you an idea of a specific article than I need to read for understand why this code is an ugly hack?

Comment: (**BTW**: Sorry if I offended you/the proposer. That wasn't my intention). What happens is that `.code16gcc` is a ([known to be fragile](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/as_270.html)) *experimental* way to allow GCC code (which assumes *protected* mode and overall 32-bit stuff). Even the buddies from GNU already said they'ld never support 16-bit systems (sorry, couldn't found a reference to this, but I read it somewhere on gnu.org). **Continuation**

Comment: **Continuation**.  Based from that, you can get perfectly deep and obscure bugs in your code that may actually be compiler/assembler bugs. It's simply not a feasible option for a bootloader. Once of the links I gave you even mentions that *`.code16gcc` will work, as long as no memory is referenced by the code*. Your best alternative is to use a GRUB-style strategy, that is, create *two* bootloaders. The first-stage bootloader is a small stub in the MBR that load the second-stage bootloader **Continuation**.

Comment: **Continuation**. The second-stage bootloader can be actually pretty big, and you'll be allowed to use protected mode and even long mode! Such a bootloader can actually present you with multiple O.Ses to boot to in the screen, and even support loadable modules (GRUB does, for example). If necessary, you may return to real mode (but only for *necessary* reasons, not for convience!), such as to allow a mechanism known as [chain-loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_loading#Chain_loading_in_boot_manager_programs). Tell me if you have any other doubts! :).

Comment: Ok I understand. I had already some bugs when I have add more functions to the boot.cpp but we are able to fix them if we modify boot.ld. I start to read the intro article of OSDev Wiki. But I'm really new in Assembly language, I start it since 1 week :p

Comment: Don't worry, we have always had our first time ;). If you have any doubts (not addressed directly or correctly in the wiki), create a forum account and post some questions there. I can say from experience to you they're very good, competitive, and pacient people :). You may find me there under the same nick (KemyLand).

Comment: I take no offense. I did say all along it was `experimental` (see comments). if I wanted to make a 16 bit real mode kernel with C I'd consider using Bruce's C compiler(or MSVC 1.52c) or better yet Open Watcom. That way it won't require an 80386 to run a purely 16 bit real mode OS. The OP never said they were targeting a protected mode kernel.

Answer (score 2):

On my cross-compiler (`i686-elf-gcc (GCC) 4.9.2`), the later code produces the following (dis)assembly:

```
    boot.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <cout>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   53                      push   %ebx
   4:   bb 07 00 00 00          mov    $0x7,%ebx
   9:   8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   c:   0f be 02                movsbl (%edx),%eax
   f:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  11:   74 08                   je     1b <cout+0x1b>
  13:   80 cc 0e                or     $0xe,%ah
  16:   cd 10                   int    $0x10
  18:   42                      inc    %edx
  19:   eb f1                   jmp    c <cout+0xc>
  1b:   5b                      pop    %ebx
  1c:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  1d:   c3                      ret
```

I'm very interested in whether you're using GCC (a non-16-bit-compatible compiler) with 16-bit stuff (BIOS interrupts). If you're going to do 16-bit code, do it in full assembly! GCC will simply mess it up, because it's generating 32-bit code that will be run **on 16-bit mode**. If you want to go directly to C/C++, then what you want to write is probably not a bootloader, but a [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)). In such a (common) case, read [the unquestionable sacred ritual to initiate you into OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones). The fact that your first example works is just luck, and any minimal change may break everything, even leading to [the mythical horrifying triple fault, nightmares of kernel panics themselves](http://wiki.osdev.org/Triple_Fault).

Anyway, you're better off writing directly to VGA DMA memory than using BIOS calls (you need to get to [protected mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_mode) first, and [setup the VGA hardware and modes](http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware)
 (GRUB does this for you, but you're creating a bootloader, aren't you?)):

```
void PrintString(const char *str) {
    uint16_t *vga = (uint16_t*)0xB8000;

    for(; *str != '\0'; str++, vga++)
        *vga = ((uint16_t)0x07 << 8) | *str; // Light grey on a black background, nice!
}
```

**BTW**, you may find [the OSDev community, wiki, andforums](http://osdev.org) very useful. And, as shown in the comments, you should be using `.code16` for [real mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Real_mode) code, and your linked article already shows its age.

Comment: "GCC will simply mess it up, because it thinks it's generating 32-bit code." this part is not true, GCC generates 32-bit code, period. GAS will add 32bit-prefixes with the `.code16` setting, so this 32-bit code is runnable in real mode.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I've already addressed this issue with you in the comments of the OP. **Edit**: That part of my answer was actually a bit misleading/misunderstandable, so I changed it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Same thing in other words: "it magically works for simple code, but don't be surprised if if happens that your code jumps to the wrong place, an condition is true instead of false, or you have an undetected arithmetic overflow where it shouldn't happen"

Comment: @DanielAlder maybe it's not mature enough but I have satisfying results with `clang` and the `-m16` option .. no BIOS interrupt call was ever a problem. The only problem I encountered was some messing up at the assembly stage, which I could circumvent using GAS for that. But it was just for a simple .COM DOS executable, so not directly comparable to the attempt of writing a bootloader.